# Displaying a large number of columns in a table

Tags: design-patterns, info-visualisation, responsive-design, data-tables

I have a *Twitter Bootstrap* based table with responsive CSS.

Everything looks good but, when I try to put more columns than the *size of the table* supports, I have a line breaking.

I tried to **change font size**. But I think it would be strange or confusing for the user if I have different font sizes in each table.
So I am in a dead end.

#### Some restrictions

- Maximum width: The table must **not exceed 940 pixels**.
- **Single Table**: I can't divide the information in multiple tables.

This is what I have:

[image]

Is there a better way to display tabular data considering the restrictions?

Comment: What is your actual question - how to stop it from line-breaking using CSS, or do you want to know if there is a better way of presenting tablular data responsively?

Comment: A better way to display tabular data considering the restrictions.

Comment: I think you have conflicting requirements (from my understanding of your description). The table cannot exceed 940 pixels in width. Assumed: You can have an arbitrary number of columns in the table.

Comment: Yes, i understand that i have conflicting requirements but the analyst didn't thought in the UX. So i have to find a way to expose this tabular data as a user friendly experience.

Comment: And its not arbitrary, its exactly this number columns.

Comment: Are you saying zooming and panning are banned actions? When I hear 940px, responsive, and big table, I think tablet, which has a great built-in (and natural) zoom and pan.

Comment: Its responsive to adjust to any size of screen but the minimum requirements are that the resolution should be at least 1024x768 pixels, so given my layout, the minimum size of tables should be 940 pixels for a desktop. Im not saying that i will not support a mobile device, but most people that will use the website will be using a desktop. So at this moment im more worried with desktop than mobile browsing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First option, if you do not wish to change any other parameters, you can implement a **horizontal scroll bar**. It's not the best option, but, it does get you to show(?) the entire table with consistent size without exceeding the 940 pixel width.

Second option, make the **columns movable**. You wrap/crumple up the out of bound columns so as they only expand when the wrap/crumple is clicked on. This way, the user can customize the table to see only things he's interested in and the rest information is still available but, hidden away.

Third option, go down the path of information visualziation. If you are not hell bent on using a table, you can look into **small multiples or multivariate charts** like parallel plots, etc. depending on the type of data you have and the output you desire.

Comment: Man I really *hate* the first two options. Totally.

Answer (score 2):

Could you maybe just **"turn" the table**? It seems like you only have two rows and a lot of columns. Turning the table would make it long, but it would fit.

It would also give you more space for your values, possibly preventing them from wrapping (which makes them difficult to read / compare).

Comment: Perhaps, but i think it will continue to be difficult to read or compare, and will not be only two rows, can be 1-10 before enable vertical scrolling. But anyway, thanks for your reply

Comment: @John To pivot the table actually eases comparison of measures (here: decimal figures) across larger dimensions (here: >10 columns compared to <10 rows) like  in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be having ellipses at the end of the breaking text to signify continued text that's missing in the fixed column. On Mouse hover, produces a tool tip with the full text.