# Best way to print a big HTML array

Tags: website-design, ergonomics

For some reason I need to print a big array of data (2D) retrieved from the DB.

There is so many column that the array go over the screen width.

So I wonder if there is any tricks to show this kind of big HTML array in a good way.

Thanks for you help and advices!

Comment: Do the answers to [How should large table columns be handled on a responsive design](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15463/how-should-large-table-columns-be-handled-on-a-responsive-design) or [Displaying a large number of columns in a table](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37116/displaying-a-large-number-of-columns-in-a-table) answer your question?

Comment: Yes it's what I was looking for. I wanted to see differents way to do that. At the moment I use the similare tricks like the first link you gave (http://i.stack.imgur.com/agfzx.png) except that I just show all the checkboxes out of the selectBox.
Thanks